Conditional expectation and an invariant measure
Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, a sigma-algebra $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, a random variable $X \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a measurable function $\phi \colon \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$.
Assume the following three properties:
$$ X \circ \phi = X, \qquad \phi^{-1}(\Sigma) \subseteq \Sigma , \qquad \phi_*\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}. $$
I am hoping to show that there exists a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X|\Sigma]$ that is $\phi^{-1}(\Sigma)$-measurable.
Intuitively, this should be true since the invariance of $\mathbb{P}$ under $\phi$ tells us that all the relevant stuff happens $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. on $\phi^{-1}(\mathcal{A})$.
The following is what I explored so far.
Namely, the desired statement is equivalent to each of:
(1) $\mathbb{E}[X|\Sigma] = \mathbb{E}[X|\phi^{-1}(\Sigma)]$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
(2) $\mathbb{E}[X|\Sigma]$ is $\phi$-invariant $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
(3) For any Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ there exists an $A \in \phi^{-1}(\Sigma)$ such that the symmetric difference of $A$ and $\mathbb{E}[X|\Sigma]^{-1}(B)$ has $\mathbb{P}$-measure zero.
That (2) is equivalent follows from $\mathbb{E}[X|\Sigma] \circ \phi = \mathbb{E}[X \circ \phi|\phi^{-1}(\Sigma)]$.
Any ideas and pointers are welcome.
Cheers!

It seems to me that a conclusion one can take is that $E[\mathbf{1}{\phi^{-1}(A)}X]=E[\mathbf{1}{A}X]$ for any $A \in {\Sigma}$. However, I don't see how one may link this result to the desired conclusion.

I obtained my desired conclusion under an additional hypothesis, which happens to be satisfied in my context. For future readers, it may still be interesting if someone finds an answer (positive or counterexample) to the question without this additional hypothesis. Said hypothesis is that any $\Sigma_{\infty}$-measurable function $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is automatically $\phi$-invariant, where $\Sigma_{\infty} := \bigcap_{k \geq 1} \phi^{-k}(\Sigma)$.
